# Exception during bindservice

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service

I get the following error when I try to do a bindService from my application. I am working with Android source code and I am sure that this service which I try to bind is not started from elsewhere. I have confirmed this through Settings -> Applications -> Running, where it shows the running services.

```
01-02 00:06:54.531: INFO/PowerManagerService(425): Start Light.setBrightness(), [20],  [3]
01-02 00:06:56.473: INFO/PowerManagerService(425): Start Light.setBrightness(), [130], [3]
01-02 00:06:58.055: WARN/dalvikvm(4956): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40b70390)
01-02 00:06:58.055: WARN/ActivityManager(425): Permission Denial: Accessing service ComponentInfo{jp.co.abc.android.omrsettings/jp.co.xyz.bluetooth.profile.TIPServer} from   pid=4956, uid=10158 requires jp.co.abc.android.OMRSettings.permission.Access
01-02 00:06:58.065: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4956): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.SecurityException: Not allowed to bind to service Intent {      act=jp.co.xyz.bluetooth.api.ITimeServer }
at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1187)
at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:370)
at jp.co.abc.middleware.tip.LeTimeServerProfile.startTimeServer(LeTimeServerProfile.java:45)
at jp.co.abc.tip.TimeActivity.onClick(TimeActivity.java:49)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3511)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14133)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4507)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:787)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:554)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-02 00:06:58.095: WARN/ActivityManager(425): Force finishing activity      jp.co.abc.tip/.TimeActivity
```

Strange part is that, this error does not occur when I remove a particular application from the device. Can someone please tell me what might be the reason for my getting this error in the presence of this application and does not when I remove this application?

Any help is much appreciated.

**EDIT**

This is the code I use to do bindservice:

```
mContext.bindService(new Intent("jp.co.xyz.bluetooth.api.ITimeServer"),  time_connection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);

ServiceConnection time_connection = new ServiceConnection() {
     public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service){
         mTime = ITimeServer.Stub.asInterface(service);
         try {
             mTime.startTIPServer(callback,Constants.TIME_SOURCE_CELLULAR_NETWORK,46);
         } catch (RemoteException e) {
             Log.e(TAG, " startTIPServer error "); 
         }
     }

    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name){
        mTime = null;
     }
  };
```

Comment: please add your code....

Answer (score 0):

The error is a permissions error. It looks like your application needs to have the permission `jp.co.abc.android.OMRSettings.permission.Access`. Add this to your manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="jp.co.abc.android.OMRSettings.permission.Access"/>
```